# .NET Core Patch JsonPatchDocument works locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a very simple ASP.NET Core app which works perfectlly on my local machine.
When I publish my project everything works (GET, POST, DELETE) but not partially update (PATCH). I use `JsonPatchDocument<T>`. This is the code:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public IActionResult PartiallyUpdateNote(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<NoteForUpdateDto> patches)
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Partial update of #{0}. Patches: {1}", id, patches);

            if (patches == null) // <------ THIS IS ALWAYS TRUE 
            {
                _log.LogError("Invalid patch format");
                return BadRequest("Invalid patch format?");
            }
```

This is json I try to send from Postman:

> PATCH http://tomasz.look24.net/api/notes/1
>   headers:
>   Content-Type=application/json
>    Raw: [{ "op": "replace", "path":
>   "/title", "value": "ne555e" }]

This is log from server (single patch hit):

```
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Connection id ""0HL2VB6EGP0A9"" bad request data: ""Unexpected end of request content"" (86f1a409)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.<ReadAsyncAwaited>d__4.MoveNext()
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Executing action method "notes.api.Controllers.NotesController.PartiallyUpdateNote (notes.api)" with arguments (["1", ""]) - ModelState is Invalid (ba7f4ac2)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Partial update of #1. Patches: null (30b5833a)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [ERR] Invalid patch format (b8690943)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext". (4e968210)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Executed action "notes.api.Controllers.NotesController.PartiallyUpdateNote (notes.api)" in 119502.6086ms (afa2e885)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00 0HL2VB6EI3TIB [INF] Request finished in 119503.2131ms 400 text/plain; charset=utf-8 (15c52c40)
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00  [INF] Connection id ""0HL2VB6EGP0A9"" bad request data: ""Unexpected end of request content"" (86f1a409)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.ReadAsyncImplementation(ArraySegment`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody.Consume(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
2017-02-27T22:46:46.1647691+01:00  [INF] Connection id ""0HL2VB6EGP0A9"" communication error (46f6d175)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer
```

I got this log after 2 minutes with message:

> Server Error
>
> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

What can be wrong? Is there something missing in server configuration?
When I try to get data as a string like that:

```
public IActionResult PartiallyUpdateNote(int id, [FromBody] string patches)
```

Everything is fine on the server side. There must be something with PartiallyUpdateNote (I believe) which always return null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It works when I change PATCH to POST

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
```

I wonder why?

Comment: Are you running this behind IIS?

Comment: Yes. At www.webio.pl